# How to avoid new line in readline() function in python 3x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, newline

I am a new to python programming. I've followed the "Learn python the hard way" book but that is based on python 2x.

```
def print_one_line(line_number,f):
    print(line_number,f.readline())
```

In this function every time it prints **A line** and a **new line**.

```
1 gdfgty

2 yrty

3 l
```

I read the documentary that if i put a **, (comma)** after **readline()**
then it won't print a new **\n**. 
Here is the documentary:

> Why are there empty lines between the lines in the file? The
>   readline() function returns the \n that's in the file at the end of
>   that line. This means that print's \n is being added to the one
>   already returned by readline() fuction. To change this behavior simply add a ,
>   (comma) at the end of print so that it doesn't print its own .

When I run the file with **python 2x** then it is OK, but when I do it in **python 3x** then the newline is printed. How to avoid that newline in **python 3x**?

Comment: You can use `end=''` in your call to `print`.

Comment: @xnx yap,it work. Thanks.

Comment: @LukasGraf, Many of the question for python 2x. I think that is for python 2x.

Comment: `readline.rstrip()` will cover both 2 and 3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Can you write the code how i use readline.rstrip() ?  I try to use but it says     AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Comment: sorry, that was a typo `readline().rstrip()`

Answer (score 6):

Since your content already contains the newlines you want, tell the `print()` function not to add any by using the optional `end` argument:

```
def print_one_line(line_number,f):
    print(line_number,f.readline(), end='')
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside the other ways, you could also use:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(f.readline())
```

Works with every Python version to date.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than skipping the newline on output, you can strip it from the input:

```
print(line_number, f.readline().rstrip('\n'))
```